# Recursive Dec to Bin Function and saving the results in a string in C language

Tags: c, string, recursion, binary, decimal

I have the following exercise:

> Write a recursive function  recDecToBin that takes 2 arguments as
> input. The first is a  natural  number that needs to be converted into
> a binary number system. The second is a string where the result should
> be saved.

I wrote the following solution but I don't like it. Is there a better method to deal with the memory and keep tracking of the storing location?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int Global = 0;  // this global variable helps with case of input 0

void recDecToBin(int n, char* result){
    Global++;
    if(Global == 1 && n == 0){    // if input 0 , results will be 0
        result[0] = '0';    
    } else {
        if (n > 0){
            int dig;
            char *a;
            dig = n % 2;    // 0 or 1 to be written
            if (dig == 1){
                a = "1";
            } else {
                a = "0";
            }
            recDecToBin(n/2, result); // recursive call
            strncat(result,a,1);      // adding the results
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int n;                // user input
    char result[30]="";   // storing string
    scanf("%d", &n);      // reading input 
    recDecToBin(n, result); // calling the function
    printf("%s", result);  // printing resutls
    return 0;           
}
```

Comment: The closest representation of a natural number would be an unsigned int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need the global variable. Also the global variable is sort of cheating on the number of arguments and makes the function usable only once. So you are justified in not liking that.

Without it your solution can be condensed to

```
void recDecToBin(int n, char* result){
    if(n<2){
        strcpy(result, n?"1":"0");
    } else {
        recDecToBin(n/2, result); // recursive call
        strncat(result, n%2?"1":"0", 1);      // adding the results
    }
}
```

(the else branch is equivalent to yours, the main point is the `if (n<2)`)

Comment: Looking back at this solution ... I find it amazingly beautiful. Thank you sir for your time and support.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better method to deal with the memory and keep tracking of the storing location?

Caller allocation is ideal and should be used whenever feasible, since that separates the two unrelated functions memory allocation and the actual algorithm.

In this case though, you know the maximum size of the output. It will be `8 * sizeof(int)` characters + 1 extra for the null terminator. (Pedantically `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int)`.) So you could have written the function as:

`void recDecToBin(int n, char result[8*sizeof(int)+1])`

This is just self-documenting code though, there's no technical difference compared to `char*`.

Implementation-wise, you should be able to get rid of the global variable and the slow, dangerous recursion both. Looking at the disassembly of your code in some mainstream compilers, they all fail to inline your code. It is horribly inefficient and the recursion is mostly to blame. But also the repeated `strcat` calls.

You should write all of this with a plain, readable loop instead:

```
const size_t size = 8*sizeof(int);
char bin_str [size+1];
unsigned int val = 123456;  

for(size_t i=0; i<size; i++)
{
  bin_str[size-i-1] = (val & 1) + '0';
  val >>= 1;
}  
bin_str[size] = '\0';
puts(bin_str);
```

Optionally drop leading zeroes:

```
const char* str = strchr(bin_str, '1');
puts(str?str:"0");
```

This also got rid of some needless branching.

Comment: "But the goal was to practice recursion" Why! Why was the goal to write an inefficient, unsafe and unreadable program? Ask your teacher this.

Comment: The exercise is one of a series of exercises (10 in total) teaching us the concept of recursions, starting with the famous (calculate the factorial) exercise and increasing complexity gradually although it's not the best implementation.